# Add a css class on td of table according to TD less or more value

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table in html with two td content in it. it is a dynamic td. I want to implement the functionality like if in each of table row, each big td value text color displayed as green and less value text display as red;

Please find my source code:

```
forData+='<tr><td>'+forPlant+'</td><td>'+forAsking+'</td><td>'+forProduction+'</td></tr>';
                $(".forTable").append(forData);
                if(forAsking<forProduction){
                    console.info("Less value");
//-----here I want to display Whatever value is less it displayed as red and other is green
                }else{
  //---same manner followed in there as well
                    console.info("More Asking");
                }
```

Comment: Can you compare the values first then append data. So that before appending data you can add color css for those values

Comment: It is also not working....

Comment: Fine, try the below answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create 2 classes for those colors

```
.green{
color:green;
}

.red{
color:red;
}
```

Then first compare the values then  append the result.

```
forData+='<tr><td>'+forPlant+'</td>';

if(forAsking<forProduction){

                   forData+='<td class="green">'+forProduction+'</td><td class="red">'+forAsking+'</td>';

                }else{

                    forData+='<td class="green">'+forAsking+'</td><td class="red">'+forProduction+'</td>';
                }

forData+= '</tr>';

 $(".forTable").append(forData);
```

[You can see the demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/Ramkee/w51y1y78/3/)

Comment: Let me know is this what you want ?

Comment: Cool... Go ahead!!